# Issues with Hangman - buttons not responding correctly

Tags: java

I am currently working on a Hangman based GUI game for an assignment for college.  I have a console based version that works the way that I want it to, but transferring this into a GUI based version is proving tricky.  So far I have the basic layout etc in the GUI.  However the buttons are not acting as I would want them to, they are all showing that they are not in the word.  I have been going round in circles with this issue, any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestHangman 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Hangman sample = new Hangman();
        sample.setTitle("Hangman Game");
        sample.setSize(800, 500);
        sample.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sample.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the main code for the game so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Hangman extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener
{
    private static final ActionListener letterHandler = null;
    private Container cPane, cn;
    private JLabel lblTitle, lblTitle2, lblTitle3, lblTitle4, btn2, btn3, btn4;
    private JButton btnExit, btnStart;
    private JButton [] btn = new JButton[26];
    private JPanel pNorth, pSouth, pEast, pWest, pCenter, p3;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private Font fnt;

    private JMenuBar mb;
    private JMenu mSystem;
    private JMenuItem mIRules, mIDev, mIRestart, mIExit;

    private static String hiddenCountry;
    static StringBuilder currentGuess;
    private static ArrayList<Character> previousGuesses = new ArrayList<>();

    static int maxTries = 7;
    static int currentTry = 0;
    int outputTry = maxTries - currentTry;

    boolean doYouWantToPlay = true;
    static char guess;

    ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
    private static FileReader fileReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedFileReader;


    Hangman() throws IOException
    {
        fnt = new Font( "Monospaced", 0, 24 );
        setFont(fnt);

        initializeStreams();
        setHiddenCountry(pickCountry());
        currentGuess = initializeCurrentGuess();

        mb = new JMenuBar();
        mSystem = new JMenu("File");
        mIDev = new JMenuItem("Developer");
        mIRules = new JMenuItem("Rules");
        mIRestart = new JMenuItem("Restart");
        mIExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        mIDev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Developer: Ryan Smith");
            }
        });

        mIRules.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hangman is a guessing game where the word"
                                    + "\n to guess is represented by dashes.  The player"
                                    + "\n is given the option to enter a letter.  If the letter"
                                    + "\n guessed is contained in the word, the letter will"
                                    + "\n replace the dash in its appropriate placement."
                                    + "\n You cannot exceed 7 wrong guesses or else you"
                                    + "\n lose.  Words are selected randomly.", "Instructions",
                                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }// end actionPerformed method
        });

        mIRestart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                dispose();
                mIRestart.setVisible(true);
                Hangman sample = null;
                try {
                    sample = new Hangman();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                sample.setTitle("Hangman Game");
                sample.setSize(800, 500);
                sample.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                sample.setVisible(true);
            }// end actionPerformed method
        });

        mIExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        mSystem.add(mIDev);
        mSystem.add(mIRules);
        mSystem.add(mIRestart);
        mSystem.add(mIExit);
        mb.add(mSystem);
        setJMenuBar(mb);

        cPane = getContentPane();
        cPane.setBackground(new Color (236, 128, 19));

        cn = getContentPane();
        //cn.setLayout(new BorderLayout (5,5));
        cn.setBackground(new Color (236, 128, 19));

        pNorth = new JPanel();
        pSouth = new JPanel();
        pEast = new JPanel();
        pWest = new JPanel();
        pCenter = new JPanel();
        p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout (3, 10));

        pCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout (3,9,0,0));
        pWest.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,10,10));
        pEast.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,10,10));
        pSouth.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,10,1,1));
        pCenter.setLayout(null);

        lblTitle = new JLabel(" Hangman ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        lblTitle.setBackground(new Color (38, 29, 226));
        lblTitle.setOpaque(true);
        lblTitle.setForeground(Color.white);
        pNorth.add(lblTitle);

        lblTitle2 = new JLabel("" + getActualCurrentGuess(), SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTitle2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        lblTitle2.setBackground(new Color (38, 29, 226));
        lblTitle2.setOpaque(true);
        lblTitle2.setForeground(Color.white);
        pCenter.add(lblTitle2);
        lblTitle2.setBounds(1,275,650,30);

        lblTitle4 = new JLabel("" + Hangman.hiddenCountry, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTitle4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        lblTitle4.setBackground(new Color (38, 29, 226));
        lblTitle4.setOpaque(true);
        lblTitle4.setForeground(Color.white);
        pCenter.add(lblTitle4);
        lblTitle4.setBounds(150,1,500,30);

        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            JButton btnX = new JButton();
            btn[i] = btnX;
            btn[i].setText("" + (char)('A'+ i));
            btn[i].addActionListener(this);
            pSouth.add(btn[i]);

            btn[i].addActionListener(letterHandler);

        }   


        cn.add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnStart = new JButton(" Restart ");
        btnStart.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnStart.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        btnStart.setForeground(Color.white);
        btnStart.setOpaque(true);
        btnStart.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        //pEast.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //pEast.add(lblTitle);
        pWest.add(btnStart);

        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                dispose();
                mIRestart.setVisible(true);
                Hangman sample = null;
                try 
                {
                    sample = new Hangman();
                } 
                catch (IOException e1) 
                {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                sample.setTitle("Hangman Game");
                sample.setSize(800, 500);
                sample.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                sample.setVisible(true);
            }// end actionPerformed method
        });


        btn2 = new JLabel(" Tries Remaining " + outputTry);
        btn2.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btn2.setBackground(new Color (38, 29, 226));
        btn2.setForeground(Color.white);
        btn2.setOpaque(true);
        btn2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        //pWest.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //pWest.add(btn2);
        pWest.add(btn2);

        cPane.add(pNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        cPane.add(pSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        cPane.add(pWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
        cPane.add(pEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
        cPane.add(pCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //btnExit.addActionListener(this);

        pCenter.addMouseListener(this);
        pNorth.addMouseListener(this);
        pSouth.addMouseListener(this);
        pEast.addMouseListener(this);
        pWest.addMouseListener(this);
        }




    protected void Hangman() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public char getText(String string)
    {
        return guess;
    }

    public char setText(String string, char guess)
    {
            return Hangman.guess = guess;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == btn[j])
            {
                Hangman.guess = btn[j].getText().charAt(0);
                btn[j].setVisible(false);

                if(Hangman.playGuess(guess))
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }


    }//end actionPerformed Method

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
    }


    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void initializeStreams() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            File inFile = new File("F:\\Java Programs\\IntroJavaPrograms\\src\\hangmanapplication\\countriesnospaces.txt");

            fileReader = new FileReader(inFile);
            bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
            while (currentLine != null)
            {
                countries.add(currentLine);
                currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
            }
            bufferedFileReader.close();
            fileReader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not initiate streams");
        }
    }

    public String pickCountry()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int wordIndex = Math.abs(rand.nextInt()) % countries.size();
        return countries.get(wordIndex).toUpperCase();
    }

    public StringBuilder initializeCurrentGuess()
    {
        StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < getHiddenCountry().length() * 2; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                current.append("_");
            }
            else
            {
                current.append(" ");
            }
        }

        return current;
    }

    public String getActualCurrentGuess()
    {
        return "Country to Guess: " + currentGuess.toString();
    }

    public static boolean gameOver()
    {
        if (playerWin())
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations!!! You Won!!! You guessed the country was " + getHiddenCountry());
            return true;
        }
        else if (playerLose())
        {
            System.out.println(addWholeMan());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("HANGMAN - You Lose!!!  The country was " + getHiddenCountry());
            System.out.println();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean playerWin()
    {
        String guess = getCondensedCurrentGuess();
        return guess.equals(getHiddenCountry());
    }

    public static String getCondensedCurrentGuess()
    {
        String guess = currentGuess.toString();
        return guess.replace(" ", "");
    }

    public static boolean playerLose()
    {
        return currentTry >= maxTries;

    }

    public static boolean letterAlreadyGuessed(char guess)
    {
        return getPreviousGuesses().contains(guess);
    }

    public static boolean playGuess(char guess)
    {
        boolean isItAGoodGuess = false;
        //boolean isItAGoodGuess = true;
        getPreviousGuesses().add(guess);

        for(int i = 0; i < getHiddenCountry().length(); i++)
        {
            if (getHiddenCountry().charAt(i) == guess)
            {
                currentGuess.setCharAt(i * 2, guess);
                isItAGoodGuess = true;

                System.out.print("That letter is in the country's name!!");
            }
        }

        if (!isItAGoodGuess)
        {
            currentTry++;
            System.out.print("That letter is not in the country's name");
        }

        return isItAGoodGuess;
    }

    public String drawMan()
    {
        switch(currentTry)
        {
            case 0: return noMan();
            case 1: return addMandHead();
            case 2: return addManBody();
            case 3: return addManFirstArm();
            case 4: return addManSecondArm();
            case 5: return addManFirstLeg();
            //case 6: return addWholeMan();
            default : return addWholeMan();

        }
    }

    private static String addWholeMan() 
    {
        return "\t - - - - -\n"+
                "\t|        |\n"+
                "\t|        0 \n"+
                "\t|       /|\\ \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|       / \\\n"+
               "\t|\\         \n"+
               "\t|_\\\n";
    }

    private String addManFirstLeg() 
    {
        return "\t - - - - -\n"+
                "\t|        |\n"+
                "\t|        0 \n"+
                "\t|       /|\\ \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|       / \n"+
               "\t|\\         \n"+
              "\t|_\\\n";
   }

   private String addManSecondArm() 
    {
       return "\t - - - - -\n"+
                "\t|        |\n"+
                "\t|        0 \n"+
                "\t|       /|\\ \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|        \n"+
               "\t|\\         \n"+
              "\t|_\\\n";
    }

    private String addManFirstArm() 
    {
        return "\t - - - - -\n"+
                "\t|        |\n"+
                "\t|        0 \n"+
                "\t|       /| \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|        \n"+
               "\t|\\         \n"+
              "\t|_\\\n";
    }

    private String addManBody() 
    {
        return "\t - - - - -\n"+
                "\t|        |\n"+
                "\t|        0 \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|        | \n"+
                "\t|        \n"+
               "\t|\\         \n"+
              "\t|_\\\n";
    }

    private String addMandHead() 
    {
        return "\t - - - - -\n"+
                "\t|        |\n"+
                "\t|        0 \n"+
                "\t|         \n"+
                "\t|         \n"+
                "\t|         \n"+
                "\t|        \n"+
               "\t|\\         \n"+
              "\t|_\\\n";
    }

    private String noMan() 
    {
        return "\t - - - - -\n"+
               "\t|        |\n"+
               "\t|         \n"+
               "\t|         \n"+
               "\t|         \n"+
               "\t|         \n"+
               "\t|         \n"+
              "\t|\\         \n"+
             "\t|_\\\n";
    }

    public static String getHiddenCountry() 
    {
        return hiddenCountry;
    }

    public void setHiddenCountry(String hiddenCountry) 
    {
       Hangman.hiddenCountry = hiddenCountry;

    }

    public static ArrayList<Character> getPreviousGuesses() 
    {
        return previousGuesses;
    }

    public void setPreviousGuesses(ArrayList<Character> previousGuesses) 
    {
        Hangman.previousGuesses = previousGuesses;
    }

}
```

The txt file countriesnospaces contains the following list of countries:

Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
Andorra
Angola
Anguilla
Antarctica
Argentina
Armenia
Aruba
Australia
Austria
Azerbaijan
Bahamas
Bahrain
Bangladesh
Barbados
Belarus
Belgium
Belize
Benin
Bermuda
Bhutan
Bolivia
Bosnia
Botswana
Brazil
Brunei
Bulgaria
Burkina
Burundi
Cambodia
Cameroon
Canada
Cayman
Chad
Chile
China
Cocos
Colombia
Comoros
Congo
Croatia
Cuba
Cyprus
Denmark
Djibouti
Dominica
Ecuador
Egypt
Eritrea
Estonia
Ethiopia
Fiji
Finland
France
Gabon
Gambia
Georgia
Germany
Ghana
Gibraltar
Greece
Greenland
Grenada
Guadeloupe
Guam
Guatemala
Guinea
Guyana
Haiti
Honduras
Hungary
Iceland
India
Indonesia
Iran
Iraq
Ireland
Israel
Italy
Jamaica
Japan
Jordan
Kazakhstan
Kenya
Kiribati
Kuwait
Kyrgyzstan
Laos
Latvia
Lebanon
Lesotho
Liberia
Libya
Liechtenstein
Lithuania
Luxembourg
Macau
Macedonia
Madagascar
Malawi
Malaysia
Maldives
Mali
Malta
Martinique
Mauritania
Mauritius
Mayotte
Mexico
Micronesia
Moldova
Monaco
Mongolia
Montserrat
Morocco
Mozambique
Myanmar
Namibia
Nauru
Nepal
Netherlands
Nicaragua
Niger
Nigeria
Niue
Norway
Oman
Pakistan
Palau
Panama
Paraguay
Peru
Philippines
Pitcairn
Poland
Portugal
Qatar
Reunion
Romania
Rwanda
Samoa
Senegal
Seychelles
Singapore
Slovenia
Somalia
Spain
Sudan
Suriname
Swaziland
Sweden
Switzerland
Syria
Taiwan
Tajikistan
Tanzania
Thailand
Togo
Tokelau
Tonga
Tunisia
Turkey
Turkmenistan
Tuvalu
Uganda
Ukraine
Uruguay
Uzbekistan
Vanuatu
Venezuela
Vietnam
Yemen
Yugoslavia
Zaire
Zambia
Zimbabwe

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you try to debug the part where it compares the `guess` with the `charAt(i)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the playGuess method deals with the comparison does it not?  This method worked in the console based version that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the design flaws that might be within your code I will try to address your direct question.

When you are calling the following line to determine which text the button has:

```
Hangman.guess = getText("" + (char)('A' + j));
```

You are trying to retrieve it from the `guess` variable, while clearly you need to just retrieve the text of the button, so the call to get the text from the button in your case would be as follows `btn[index].getText()` and since you will have just one `char` in the text of each button you can retrieve that from the String by calling `charAt(0)` so in the end you can write the line as:

```
Hangman.guess = btn[j].getText().charAt(0);
```

After you finish your game, I would strongly recommend you to submit it for review in the [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which will give you some good advice on how to improve the structure/readability etc. of your code.

Comment: This only fixed half the issue, the letters are being recognized as in the word but not actually displaying in the GUI.